# How to recover total distance in of optimal full matching in MatchIt?

Tags: causality, matching

It is easy to recover the total distance using optmatch::fullmatch, e.g.,

```
library(optmatch)
data(plantdist)
fm1 <- fullmatch(plantdist)
sum(unlist(matched.distances(fm1, plantdist, pres = T)))
```

How would one accomplish this using the `MatchIt` package? There doesn't seem to be a way to recover the individual pairwise distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recover individual pairwise distances from `matchit()` output, but you can supply them to `matchit()`, just as you did with `fullmatch()`, to perform the matching, and then use the same function to extract those distances. See below for an example using the `lalonde` dataset:

```r
library(optmatch); library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")

#Create distances
d1 <- optmatch::match_on(treat ~ age + educ + re74, data = lalonde,
                        method = "mahalanobis")
d2 <- MatchIt::mahalanobis_dist(treat ~ age + educ + re74, data = lalonde)

all.equal(as.matrix(d1), d2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE

#Using fullmatch()
f <- fullmatch(d1, data = lalonde)
sum(unlist(matched.distances(f, d1, pres = T)))
#> [1] 203.416

#Using matchit()
m <- matchit(treat ~ 1, data = lalonde, distance = d1,
             method = "full")
s <- m$subclass
class(s) <- c("optmatch", "factor")

sum(unlist(matched.distances(s, d1, pres = T)))
#> [1] 203.416
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>